# Create a new WooCommerce category via CLI for new products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, command-line-interface

I am using the WooCommerce CLI to import a CSV with products into WooCommerce. That works, except that I can't figure out how to create the new categories for the imported products.

my products are stored in the `$product` array. The `$product['category‘]` is a string with the category name.

```
wp wc product create --sku="'.$product['sku'].'" --type="simple" --name="'.$product['name'].'" --regular_price="'.$product['price'].'" --categories="'.$catid.'" --images="{'.$product['image'].'}" --user="'.$user.'"
```

At first I tried to use the category name unless I figured out that the --categories param needs an integer (or maybe a JSON-Object, according to another post).

Because of that I am using the following code to save the current category  id into a variable to use in product create (the categories and articles are in an loop). But it does not work as integer (`--categories=12`) or as JSON-Object `[{"id" : 12}]`.

```
$cat = shell_exec('wp wc product_cat create --name="'.$product['category'].'" --porcelain --user="'.$user.'"');
```

Just to wrap it up. At the moment the order is like that:

1. Create categories and save the current category id to $cat (works)
2. Create a new product (works) except, that the category is not set. It's marked as "uncategorized".

I know, I could load the article afterwards to set the category. But I think that's a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The problem was the quotes. Escaping the double quotes in the object did the job.

```
[{\"id\" : 12}]
```